# If G is simple and 3−regular, then κ = λ

Tags: graph-theory

Can I state that κ = λ = 3 if we have 3-regular graph G?

λ = 3 for any n, but I am not  sure for κ

**Note**: κ is the minimum number of vertices to delete to make G disconnected or trivial graph (one isolated vertex), and λ is the minimum number of edge to remove to make G disconnected.

Comment: As you guess the answer is Yes!! From [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory) ] we have : any symmetric graph of degree d, both kinds of connectivity are equal: κ(G) = λ(G) = d.

Comment: Note that not all the cubic graphs are symmetric, thus we must use this property from the same Wikipedia page: "For a vertex-transitive graph of degree d ≤ 4, both kinds of connectivity are equal: κ(G) = λ(G) = d."